# How to get string after specific string?

Tags: c#, regex

How to get string after text "playlist:" ?

```
var YT= "tag:youtube.com,2008:user:hollywoodlife09:playlist:PLDovhwKa3P88MwGzYxMDMfiAiiEWxAJYj" ;
```

**What I did :**

```
string[] s = YT.Split(':');
```

But it will give me array i.e s[0],s[1] ... and I am searching for something which can give result after specific text.

I want string after "playlist:", I know it may be easy with Regex,but currently I don't have any idea for Regex..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Substring  method

```
var output = inputString.SubString(inputString.LastIndexOf("playlist") + 8);
```

Or in this case it can be done using [`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method via `Split`:

```
string output = YT.Split(':').Last();
```

Comment: I'd use this method because this is quite a simple program and regex generally reduces readability of code greatly.

Comment: You can also split on "playlist:".

Answer (score 3):

Using regex replace, remove everything before the `:playlist:` with empty string.

```
string playlist = Regex.Replace(YT, ".*:playlist:", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

more reusably,

```
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SplitPairs(
    this string source,
    params char[] seperators)
{
    var values = source.Split(seperators);
    for(var i = 0; i < values.Length; i += 2)
    {
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
            values[i],
            values[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

so you could do,

```
var yTlookup = YT.SplitPairs(':').ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
var playList = yTLookup["playlist"];
```

---

or if you don't want an extension,

```
var segments = YS.Split(new[] { ':' });
var ySlookup = Enumerable.Range(0, segemnts.Length / 2)
    .ToDictionary(i => segments[i * 2], i => segments[(i * 2) + 1]);
```

so you can do,

```
var playlist = ysLookup["playlist"];
```

---

either approach pays off as soon as you want another value from the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The regex is `.+playlist:([^:])`